# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.UInt64' (0x10dddde88) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x12129d018)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In Swift 2.3, I must cast `UInt64` to `AnyObject` with `as!`. But It's `as` in Swift 3. Once I cast this in Swift 2.3, it crashed with the following message.

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.UInt64' (0x10dddde88) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x12129d018).

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 3 greatly differs from Swift 2.3, when it comes to casting. For example, if you run the following in an Xcode 8 playground (using the latest Swift toolchain, Xcode 8.2 in my case):

```
import Foundation
import Swift

struct Foo
{
    init()
    {

    }
}

NSStringFromClass(type(of: Foo() as AnyObject))
```

You will see, that `NSStringFromClass(type(of: Foo() as AnyObject))` will register as a `"_SwiftValue"` in the inspection column on the right.

This is because Swift 3 allows you to wrap *any* construct as an `AnyObject` using an internal `_SwiftValue` class, which can then later be unwrapped in some other part of your code.

Swift 2.3 **does not have this feature**. That is where you are erring.

But what you can do is cast `UInt64` to an `NSNumber`. This works with both Swift 2.3 and 3.0, if I recall correctly. I realize that you might be dealing with a generic type, and you might not know during compile time whether the type you're dealing with is a `UInt64` or something else; but this method should work regardless. You could use the `as?` operator as well, to handle casting errors and exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, only `Int` and `UInt` are convertible to `AnyObject` (implicitly or explicitly).

When your explicitly convert `Int` or `UInt` to `AnyObject`, you use `as` casting, not `as!`:

```
//Swift 2.3
let ui: UInt = 1234
let uiObj = ui as AnyObject

let i: Int = 5678
let iObj = i as AnyObject
```

In fact, they are automatically converted to `NSNumber`:

```
//Swift 2.3
print(uiObj.dynamicType) //->__NSCFNumber (__NSCFNumber is one of the concrete subclasses of NSNumber)
print(iObj.dynamicType)  //->__NSCFNumber
```

In Swift 3, some implicit conversions are removed, but since 3.0.1, all integer type can be converted to `NSNumber` with explicit casting:

```
//Swift 3.0.2
let ui64: UInt64 = 12345678
let ui64Obj = ui64 as AnyObject

let i8: Int8 = 123
let i8Obj = i8 as AnyObject

let ui: UInt = 1234
let uiObj = ui as AnyObject

let i: Int = 5678
let iObj = i as AnyObject

print(type(of: ui64Obj)) //->_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber (_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber is another subclass of NSNumber)
print(type(of: i8Obj))   //->_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber
print(type(of: uiObj))   //->_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber
print(type(of: iObj))    //->_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber
```

So, if you want to make nearly the same result in Swift 2 as `uint64Value as AnyObject` in Swift 3, you need to construct `NSNumber` explicitly.

```
//Swift 2.3
let ui64: UInt64 = 12345678
let ui64Obj = NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: ui64)
print(ui64Obj.dynamicType)  //->__NSCFNumber
```

Replace `uint64Value as AnyObject` to `NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: uint64Value)`.

(In fact, `_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber` is not exactly the same as `__NSCFNumber`, but that may not be your problem.)

---

By the way, when I set Legacy Swift flag to YES in Xcode 8.2, it showed a warning saying:

> Swift 2.3 is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of
>   Xcode. Migrate to Swift 3 now.

Apple is strongly encouraging us to move to Swift 3 immediately.

You'd better hurry migrating your code to Swift 3.